# How to get DATETIME of the row inserted into Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, elgg

I need to display number of users created from last login to current login in my ELGG application, but there is no field in the ElggUser to record the date & time of users created ([ElggUser Table Structure](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Engine/DataModel/Entities/ElggUser)).

So is there any way to get DATETIME of rows already inserted into Table?

Thank You

Comment: What kind of database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: @Dragony yes I'm using MySQL.

Comment: @speeday125 it seems that mysql does not keep track of that kind of info. You will need to add a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database schema of Elgg does contain this information. ElggUser extends ElggEntity that has attributes **time_created, time_updated, last_action** containing Unix timestamps representation of entity creation/modification/last action by this entity or on related content.

These attributes are stored in {DB_PREFIX}entities table and are availible as properties of all ElggEntity subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a field for recording date and time. For instance my table name is my_table and for date time using created_date then create a trigger as:

```
DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE TRIGGER `my_table_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.created_date = NOW();
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Every time for added record the trigger will hit recording the date and time of entry

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if you can alter your table, but you could add a created column like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN created timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The column created would then always have the time when a row gets inserted without further ado.

Comment: Actually I want to get timestamp of existed rows, is there any way to get that?

Comment: Sorry, no way. You can't get what you don't have.